# JFrame will not load new screen

Tags: java, swing, validation, class, jframe

I have a class that extends JFrame and works by adding in 2 panels with BoxLayout buttons, and one JTabbedPane in the center which displays graphs.

I want one of the buttons to remove all current components in the frame and add new ones.

Here are the methods used.

```
private void createAndShowGraphs() {

    ImageIcon createImageIcon(lsuLettersPath); //simple png file to fill one tab
    final JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel();
    iconLabel.setOpaque(true);
    jtp.addTab(null, icon, iconLabel);

    //Here is where the errors begin
    JPanel menu = new JPanel();
    menu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menu, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    //I want this button to remove all components currently in the JFrame and replace them with new components specified in the createAndShowIntro() method
    menu.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Intro Pane") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //I've also tried putting removeAll in the Intro method
            removeAll();
            createAndShowIntro();
        }
    }));

    add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(menu, BorderLayout.WEST);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
private void createAndShowIntro() {
    System.out.println("Made it to Intro");
    //all I want is a blank JLabel with the String "test" to show up
    JPanel test = new JPanel();
    test.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("test");
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    test.add(label);
    add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    test.revalidate();
    label.revalidate();
    validate();
    test.repaint();
    label.repaint();
    repaint();

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

When I call createAndShowGraphs() in main() and then hit the 'Intro' button, everything freezes and nothing is actually removed. I know it makes it the Intro method because of the "Made it to Intro" string output to the terminal.

I've tried all kinds of combinations of invalidate(), validate(), revalidate(), repaint() on the labels and on the frame itself. Really frustrated because I don't know how else I'm going to be able to display 3 different screens to switch back and forth between while only actually displaying one at a time.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't call `removeAll` on a `JFrame`, it removes the `JRootPane` on which everything else is contained.  Use `getContentPane#removeAll` instead. Take a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

Comment: Wow. I'm embarrassed to say how long I was struggling with that. This answered my question exactly. Thank you so very much!